# Session Overwrite

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a session variable which is accessed by multiple users through different pc's...so my question is do session variables overwrite when same login credentials are associated?

Answer (score 2):

Session variables / objects are 'unique to users', also unique to browsers and are not over written by other users. You can read more about session state [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> Sessions are identified by a unique identifier that can be read by
>   using the SessionID property. When session state is enabled for an
>   ASP.NET application, each request for a page in the application is
>   examined for a SessionID value sent from the browser. If no SessionID
>   value is supplied, ASP.NET starts a new session and the SessionID
>   value for that session is sent to the browser with the response. [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Session Variables / Cookies are unique to Users/Browsers only. However you are confusing sessions with Application variables....which are Global to users. Sessions are generated via Webserver.